# How to configure ActiveMQ and WSO2CEP?

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-cep

I'm usign WSO2CEP 3.1.0 and I go through steps provided in the website guide but still I get the following error. what am i doing wrong?

I saw this was a bug in versions prior to 3.0.0 but it says it's been fixed.

I added `activemq-broker-5.9.1.jar`, `activemq-client-5.9.1.jar`, `geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar`, `hawtbuf-1.9.jar` to `/wso2cep-3.1.0/repository/components/lib`

and added `activemq-all-5.9.1.jar`, `geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar` to `/wso2cep-3.1.0/samples/lib`,

but when I run sample 0002 I get the following error. this error was also happening when I was running the default server instance (non-sample) and creating input or output jms adapters.

```
[2011-05-15 06:15:37,327] ERROR - {BaseUtils}  JNDI lookup of name TopicConnectionFactory returned a org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory while a interface javax.jms.ConnectionFactory was expected
Exception in thread "Thread-30" org.apache.axis2.transport.base.BaseTransportException: JNDI lookup of name TopicConnectionFactory returned a org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory while a interface javax.jms.ConnectionFactory was expected
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.BaseUtils.handleException(BaseUtils.java:168)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adaptor.jms.internal.util.JMSUtils.lookup(JMSUtils.java:363)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adaptor.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.<init>(JMSConnectionFactory.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adaptor.jms.JMSEventAdaptorType.createJMSAdaptorListener(JMSEventAdaptorType.java:303)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adaptor.jms.JMSEventAdaptorType.tryStartAdaptor(JMSEventAdaptorType.java:262)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adaptor.jms.internal.ds.JMSEventAdaptorServiceHolder.loadLateStartEventAdaptors(JMSEventAdaptorServiceHolder.java:66)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adaptor.jms.internal.ds.JMSEventAdaptorServiceHolder$1.run(JMSEventAdaptorServiceHolder.java:43)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried in a fresh CEP 3.1.0 pack, with jars that you specified above and it is working fine without any issue.. Can you please check what are the jars exists in the dropins directory of the server..

All the samples which are in CEP pack tested and works fine.. I believe in your case there are some more additional jars are added to lib or dropins directory.. Can you please check..

Answer (score 0):

In documentation (Input/Output JMS Adaptors) you have something like this:

> 2.Add the following ActiveMQ JMS-specific JAR files to  /repository/components/lib/ directory.
>   /lib/activemq-core-xxx.jar
>   /lib/geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar

and I don't see activemq-(your_jar_version).jar  in yours libs. So maybe you can try with this solution.

Comment: This is for activemq versions 5.7 and before. Activemq's structure has changed and so has the documentation of WSO2CEP.